# Laravel - Run task in interval based from database

Tags: php, laravel

I have email alert feature for users. They can activate whether they want to get alerts on daily or weekly basis.
In alerts table I have columns: uid (userID), interval, searchTerm, emailSentAt, etc...

So, I have this command:

```
public function handle()
    {

        $user = Alert::select('alerts.id', 'search', 'email', 'interval', 'emailSentAt')->join('users', 'alerts.uid', '=', 'users.id')->whereNotNull('search')->distinct()->get();

        foreach ($user as $u) {
            $cl      = new SphinxSearch();
            $results = $cl->search('@*' . $u->search, 'spots');
            $results = $cl->limit(10);
            $results = $cl->setMatchMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
            $results = $cl->setSortMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC, "start");
            $results = $cl->get();

            Mail::send('emails.newSearchAlert', ['u' => $u, 'results' => $results], function ($m) use ($u) {

                $m->from('noreply@mydomain.tv', 'My Company');

                $m->to($u->email)->subject('Your search alert - ' . $u->search);
            });

            $u->emailSentAt = Carbon::now();
            $u->save();
        }
    }
```

Here I send emails and save the sent time in `emailSentAt` column.

And in Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('email:user')->dailyAt('13:00');
    }
```

For `interval` column in database I have two values: 0 (daily) and 1 (weekly).

How can I run this command based on interval column? If user has 0 I want to send him email every day at 13:00, and 1 I want to send weekly.

Comment: I think you have a wrong approach on this issue. 

Why don't you `daily` run the schedule command, but do the checks for sending the email in the command itself. 

You probably need an extra field for this, like "last_sent_date" or something, so you can calculate (easy with Carbon) know how many days it's been since you last sent the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new task to the schedule like this:

```
$schedule->command('email:user', ['weekly'=> true])->weekly('15:00');
```

And then in handle() i would add this:

```
$weekly = $this->argument('weekly');
```

And then use $weekly to filter the query. This way you can chose when to send the daily and the weekly mails.

Edit: Sorry, add/change this to you command as well, it tells the command that the weekly argument is optional:

```
protected $signature = 'email:user {weekly?}';
```

Comment: I get this `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  The "weekly" argument does not exist.
`

Comment: There is an example for weekly commands in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Comment: Hm, sorry but I do not understand how can I select which command is going to be sent. If I have `php artisan email:user 1` how can I assure that this is going to send weekly?